# Best algorithm for static memory allocations

Tags: memory, allocation

If we have a list of memory allocations (ie. their sizes, when they are first used and when they are last used), what is currently the best algorithm to calculate offsets for the allocations? Here "best" means that speed is preferred more than absolutely perfect packing.

Comment: Keep a pointer to the free space (preferably in a register). Every time an allocation is requested, increment the pointer by the size of the allocation (and return the old value). Done.

Comment: Yes, what you described is a basic linear allocator. However, I know my allocation sizes and times in advanced and I'm searching a way that would pack them to conserve as much memory as possible.

Comment: The algorithm I'm imagining would not (for example) put small allocations into a free area in the beginning of the memory if there's a big one coming up. Because otherwise it would leave an empty area in the beginning, put that big allocation in the end and peak memory consumption would be higher.